# 2.8 Ambient Occlusion of World Background

Tags: rendering, animation, shaders, lighting

[image]

I have an animation imported from Mixamo.  In 2.79  I could not make the background transparent in animation only on single images.  So I used a green screen for the world background.  In there it was simple for me to click the Ambient Occlusion to eliminate the green shading on the character animation I was generating.

I don't know how to achieve this same effect in 2.8.  I have reviewed some of the online videos but can't get a handle on it.  I'm still trying to learn the 2.8 interface.

What are the simple steps to remove the green tint from the character displayed in the attached image?

Comment: Is the background you want to use for compositing static (doesn't move/change)? You could use Blender's compositor to combine render and footage directly.

Comment: Yes that is an option. But without moving my video back and forth I really just want to add a monochrome background, that I can turn transparent when added to video in the video editor.  But you have given me two ideas for future projects I working on thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the transparent background you need to enable *Transparent* in the *Film* panel. If you want to enable or disable this option for specific frames:

1. Move to the first frame in the timeline
2. Set the state of the *Transparent* checkbox (enable if you want the majority of the frames to be transparent, disable if you want most frames without transparency)
3. Hover over the checkbox with your mouse cursor and <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe.

Repeat the process with other frames of the animation where you want the opposite setting for the transparency. The keyframe setting will be applied until the next frame with a keyframe, which means for disabling transparency for one frame only, you will need to activate it again in the next one.

Make sure that the file format you're using supports alpha channels.

[image]

---

In order to remove the green lighting from the project, you will need to change the color or texture of the *World*. *Ambient Occlusion* is also in the *World* tab, if you still want to use it.

[image]

Comment: Is mpg-4 able to be compiled with an transparent alpha channel?

Comment: Video formats aren't capable of storing an alpha as far as I'm aware. Since you want to use it in compositing (if I understood you correctly) you'd want to store each frame as OpenEXR.

Comment: I actually want to use my animation with my video editor.  I want to overlay the animated character on my own video.  In the video editor I can convert green screen to transparent alpha channel. That is why I added the green. However I do not want to shade the character with the green. In 2.79 after setting the world/background to green, I simply clicked Ambient Occlusion to remove it from the character.  I am not familiar with OpenEXR.

Comment: Depends on your video editor. Blender has a video editor too. You can simply import your video and rendered image sequence into the VSE and overlay them. If your video editor is DaVinci Resolve, then it supports OpenEXR.

Comment: Yes I have viewed some tutorials on that. However, I use Filmora and I am more familiar with that for composing my videos.  I am going to try to use your suggestion for checking off Ambient Occlusion to see it that gets the results I'm looking for.  Really appreciate the help

Comment: Alternatively you could also render one video of your scene in color and another that is the mask. That would be more accurate than chroma keying with a cg greenscreen.

Comment: Boy you are way ahead of me.  I'll try and clip a short section of one of my projects and post it as an example

Comment: BTW there are video format that support alpha, see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/video_formats.html

Comment: Thanks I’ll check them out. Could you give me an up vote for asking the question, I need all the points I can get

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This is the simple result I'm trying to achieve.